# Convert a list to a map in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking for optimized solution to convert a list to map.

I have the following.

```
var lst = ['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3, 'd', 4];
```

How can I convert this into a map.

```
[{"a"=>1},{"b"=>2},{"c"=>3},{"d"=>4}]
```

Comment: do you really want an array of size 4 where each element is an object or do you mean a hashmap: ```{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4}``` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
let list = ['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3, 'd', 4];
let myMap = new Map();
let i = 0

while (i < list.length){
  if(i%2 == 0){
    myMap.set(list[i],list[i+1])
  }
  i++;
}

console.log(myMap);
```

[image]

Comment: following your %2 spirit, we may do it as a oneliner:
```new Map(lst.reduce((v,x,i)=>(i%2==0 && v.push([x,lst[i+1]]), v),[]))```

Answer (score 2):

You could slice the array, take a pair in a wrapped array and build an object for pushing into an array.

```js
var list = ['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3, 'd', 4],
    result = [],
    i = 0;

while (i < list.length) result.push(Object.fromEntries([list.slice(i, i+= 2)]));

console.log(result);
```